# Header and footer in a separate .php, with current page highlight

Tags: php, html

I didn't code for years and I probably forgot everything, but I'm trying to start again to develop my personal website.
I would like to put the div header and the div footer in a .php file so I don't have to manually modify every single page in case of modifications.
My idea was like:

header-footer.php

```
<?php function head()
       {echo '<ul>
                <li><a href="tutorial.html"' if($current == "tutorial") {echo 'class="menu_link_active"';} else {echo 'class="menu_link"';} '>Tutorials</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"' if($current == "contact") {echo 'class="menu_link_active"';} else {echo 'class="menu_link"';} '>Contatti</a></li>
               </ul>';}

function foot()
  {echo '...html...';} ?>
```

The function head() should recognize the current page to highlight it.
Then in the pages of my website I include the header-footer.php like this:

```
<head><?php include("php/header-footer.php"); ?><head>
```

Calling into the  the two functions:

```
<body><?php $current = "projemi";
            head();?>
      ...html code...
      <?php foot(); ?></body>
```

My questions are:
1) the page displays this error: ----syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';'---- and it referres to the head function. Where is the error?
2) Is it correct the process to obtain what I want or you would suggest something different?

Thanks you so much guys, and forgive me for my bad english!

Comment: You are missing the semicolon after the echo. Try to ident your code better to see this kind of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the value into the function to use

```
  <?php 
      function head($current){
         echo '<ul>
            <li><a href="tutorial.html"';
         if($current == "tutorial") {
                 echo 'class="menu_link_active"';
         }else {
                echo 'class="menu_link"';
         } 
         echo '>Tutorials</a></li><li><a href="contact.html"'; 
         if($current == "contact") {
              echo 'class="menu_link_active"';
          } else {
              echo 'class="menu_link"';
          } 
          echo '>Contatti</a></li></ul>';
        }
    ?>
```

Call your function like

```
  <?php
     $current = 'someVal';
     head($current);
  ?>
```

Comment: Looks like the real issue was you did not close your statements with semi-colons. But the functions were incorrect as well.

Comment: It worked perfectly ksealey, thanks! I completely forgot about the $current between brackets (and to close the echo function, of course)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you forgot to end your echo statement with a semicolon first off, hence the error.

```
echo '<ul>
                <li><a href="tutorial.html"'; if($current == "tutorial") {echo 'class="menu_link_active"';} else {echo 'class="menu_link"';} '>Tutorials</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"'; if($current == "contact") {echo 'class="menu_link_active"';} else {echo 'class="menu_link"';} '>Contatti</a></li>
               </ul>';
```

Also, suggestion, I believe this would be more efficient (I'd recommend to just develop an MVC-like system, but that's a bit tad too complicated for what you want do to):

```
echo '<ul>
                <li><a href="tutorial.html"'.(($current === 'tutorial') ? 'class="menu_link_active"' : 'class="menu_link"').'>Tutorials</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"'.(($current === 'contact') ? 'class="menu_link_active"' : 'class="menu_link"').'>Contatti</a></li>
               </ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks CristianHG! 
I ask you one more question, what did you mean saying that writing the code in that other way would be more efficient? Efficiency in term of performances, legibility or something else?

Comment: Performance and aesthetic. Shorthand if statements perform better, have less characters and make your code look more professional and standardized :)